# How to handle DAL for multiple layers of 1 to many relationship?

Tags: asp.net-core, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern, ravendb, data-access-layer

I have the following problem:
I have an aggregate root with multiple layers of one to many relationship.

```
Root -> has many
Child -> has many
GrandChild
```

I have  `Controller`\s that handle logic done on each layer of the aggregate root.

I do not know how to handle the data access layer.

Should i just create a repository for the aggregate root and all `Child` and `GrandChild` operations get handled through it or it would be fine to create a repository for every level ?

Furthermore the `GrandChildren` entities in my case occupy a lot of space (they contain text) , thus i  will be using a document database - `RavenDB`.

```
public class Root
{
  public int ID{get;set;}
  public IEnumerable<Child>Children;
}
public class Child
{
   public int ChildID{get;set;}
   public IEnumerable<Child>GrandChildren; //occupy a loot of space !
}
public class GrandChild
{
  public int GrandChildID{get;set;}
}

public interface IGenericRepository<T>
{
    bool Add<T>(T newValue);
    T Get<T>(int id);
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
    bool Delete(int id);   
    bool Update<T>(T value);
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class ParentController
{
    IGenericRepository<Root> repo;
    public IActionResult<Root> Get(int rootId)
    {
         return this.repo.Get(rootId);
    }
} 
public class ChildControiller_V1
{
    IGenericRepository<Child>repo;
    public IActionResult<Child> Get(int childid)
    {
          this.repo.Get(childid); //the id is unique 
    }
}
```

**Access through root**

```
 public class RootRepository:IGenericRepository<Root>
 {
     /// implementations
     public IGenericRepository<Child> GetChildRepository()
     {
            return //some implementation of IGenericRepository for Child
     }
 }
    public class ChildController_V2
    {
        IGenericRepository<Root>repo;
        public IActionResult<Child> Get(int rootId,int childid)
        {
              var root=this.repo.Get(rootId);
              var childRepo=root.GetChildRepository();
              var get= childRepo.Get(childId);

        }
    }
```

I hope you get the idea.For more layers i would do this all the way down.What would be a good approach considering the lowest entities occupy a lot of space compared to the others?

**Update**

The `Root` will have to support `Create`,`Delete` - not much happening here
The `Child` will have to support `Create`,`Delete` - (The focus will be on `GET` 
 , something like `GET  5 children starting from index=10`
 here)
The `Grandchildren` will have to support full `CRUD` with a heavy intensive work on `Update` .Their table size of `GrandChildren` will be  >>>>> all the others combined.Every `Grandchild` will  have a plain text column.
When i say `table` or `column` i am referring to their equivalent in a typical SQ L database

Comment: Hi,
I think this article can answer you question
https://ayende.com/blog/96257/document-based-modeling-auctions-bids

Comment: What kind of queries do you want to support? In general, in addition to the comment above you can create recursive map indexes to query on relationships or with the newer versions use the Graph API

Comment: Well i will have to support `create,delete` for `Parent` , `create,delete,get` for `Child` and `Create,Delete,Update and many others` for `Grandchild`.As i said the intensive work will be done on the `GrandChildren` , and the table (don't know the equivalent in ravenDB yet)  size of `GrandChildren` >>>> all the others.The grandchildren will be edited intensively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a (classic)DDD point of view, repositories return fully materialized aggregates, where aggregates represent consistency/transactional boundaries. Having children and grandchildren repositories means you give that up and with it a big benefit of DDD. That being said, you need to determine where your consistency boundaries are. Are there constraints between the entities? If not, they can be there own aggregates. Remember that aggregates don't appear in other aggregates and references from an entity should only go to an aggregate root, not some other entity in another aggregates' hierarchy.

I already mentioned a few other points that may be interesting in my answer here, specifically a direction if the data is too much. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59189413/2613363

Lastly, I will say Raven has versions (etags). Use them if you end up updating many child items.

Comment: The thing is that in my hierarchy of `Root`,`Child` and `GrandChild` i would have a  controller that deals with operations on the `Child` level.For example `get all children with index between [0,11] ` The requester would use the `GrandChild`-ren from these `Child`-ren , so they are tied in this scenario.The most intensive part  however would be a `controller` that deals with operations of `GrandChild`-ren in the context of a child.These `GrandChild` entities constitute the biggest part of the database and the most used.

Comment: If it is just for querying, that is fine. If you are making changes to child, you want to do it through root (same for grandchildren). This is to enforce consistency boundary. If there is not consistency/transaction to enforce, then maybe they shouldnt be in an aggregate together. The link goes into this a bit more.